# How to show only the selected Child from a list?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to implement a card list in an order payment page. I know how to show/hide components by using state in React.js. However, for this one, I want to only show some child components of a selected their parent component. I'm confused how I can approach this way. Can anyone have an idea for this?

**You should choose a card to pay from the list**

[image]

**Once you click a card, you will see its CVV and Zip Code inputs like the below image**

[image]

**order.jsx**

```
class AdditionalOrderDetail extends Component {

  handleSubmitPayment = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('submitted');
  }

  showCardInfo = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target);
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      showCardInfo: !prevState.showCardInfo,
    }));
  }

<form onSubmit={ this.handleSubmitPayment }>
  {card_list.map((card) => {
     return (
       <div className='card-row'>
         <div>
           <div>
             <input type='radio' name='payment-method' value='as' onClick={ this.showCardInfo } />
             <div>{card.card.card_type}</div>
               <div>ending in</div>
               <div>{card.card.card_number}</div>
             </div>
             <div>
               <div>{card.nick_name}</div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <CardInfo isShown={ showCardInfo } />
         </div>
      );
    })}
  <input type='submit' className='orange full' value='Pay Now' />
</form>

}

const CardInfo = ({ isShown }) => {
  if (isShown) {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>CVV <input type='text' /></div>
        <div>Zip Code <input type='text' /></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return null;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `showCardInfo` prop in `state` for each card. What is happening is that the same `prop` is `managing` both components:

Maybe you can handle this by modifying the card object and add a prop `showCardInfo` or similar to handle the state.

Lets say that your card object is like this:

```
const card = {
 card_type: 'Some type',
 card_number: '123123123123123',
 show_more_info: false,
 nick_name: 'My Card',
}
```

So you have to modify the jsx as :

```
      <div className='card-row'>
         <div>
           <div>
             <input type='radio' name='payment-method' value='as' onClick={ this.showCardInfo } />
             <div>{card.card.card_type}</div>
               <div>ending in</div>
               <div>{card.card.card_number}</div>
             </div>
             <div>
               <div>{card.nick_name}</div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <CardInfo isShown={ card.show_more_info } />
         </div>
```

and the method has to be modified to access the card with the click, maybe pass the id of the card to make easier to handle the selected card:

```
onClick={ () => {this.showCardInfo(e, card.id) }}
```

Comment: I'm confused what was modified the middle code snippet of your answer. It still looks the same with mine. Was that intentional or a mistake?

Comment: Check the `CardInfo` `isShown` prop is now passed the `card.show_more_info` , that is related to certain card, so if is active it will just show or hide the selected card